# Given irrational numbers $0<\gamma_1<\gamma_2<1,$ real numbers $0\leq a<b\leq 1,$ does $\exists n$ such that $\{n\gamma_1\}, \{n\gamma_2\}\in(a,b)?$

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving, irrational-numbers, pigeonhole-principle, fractional-part

For this question, $\{x\}$ means the fractional part of the real number $x.$

Given irrational numbers $0<\gamma_1<\gamma_2<1,\ $ real numbers $a,b$ with $0\leq a<b\leq 1,$ does there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\ a< \left\{ n\gamma_1 \right \} < b\ \ $ and $\ \ a< \left\{ n\gamma_2 \right \} < b\ ?$

My thoughts: For irrational $\gamma$ we have that $\{\ \{\gamma n\}:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense (in fact, equidistributed) in $[0,1].$  But I don't see how to use this.

Any thoughts/hints/ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not always .For example,if you choose $\gamma_1=\pi/8,\gamma_2=\pi/4$.The point set $\{(\{n\gamma_1\},\{n\gamma_2\}):n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is dense on

$$
C:y=\left\{\begin{align}&2x,&0\le x<\frac{1}{2}\\ 
& 2x-1,&\frac{1}{2}\le x <1
\end{align}\right..
$$
However,if you choose $a=3/8,b=5/8$,The square $[a,b]\times [a,b]$ does not intersect with $C$.

Comment: I am failing to see why your point set satisfies that property. Please can you explain?

Comment: @AdamRubinson,since $\gamma_2=2\gamma_1$,for each $n$,$(n\gamma_1,n\gamma_2)$ lies on the line $y=2x$.Take fractional part for both coordinates of the points on the line ,and you'll get the curve $C$.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. So whenever $\{n\gamma_1\}$ is close to $\frac{1}{2},$ $\{n\gamma_2\}$ isn't. This answers the question then.

Comment: Maybe the result is true if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are linearly independent over the rational numbers?

Comment: Almost there.When $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ and $1$ are rationally independent,$\{(\{n\gamma_1\},\{n\gamma_2\}):n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.This can be proved by  Multi-dimensional Weyl’s Criterion.